# Selenium Chromedriver "Failed to Load Extension"

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm running Chrome using the following Python code:

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

I am receiving the following error:

[image]

I've tried disabling extensions through code... as well as actually removing all extensions from Chrome before running the code. Neither solution has worked.

I'm running code using the following:

- ChromeDriver 2.28
- Chrome V57.0.2987.110
- Selenium 3.3.1
- Python 2.7

Comment: Alternatively, does any one know how to easily close the annoying error via the Python code?

Answer (score 6):

I run into the same kind of problem and I solved it following the answer to this other question:

[What is python's equivalent of useAutomationExtension for selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099288/what-is-pythons-equivalent-of-useautomationextension-for-selenium)

For me, the necessary part of this answer is to set the chromeOptions capability 'useAutomationExtension' to false. My code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False}}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = capabilities)
driver.get('https://www.python.org/')
```

I'm not sure if the "--disable-extensions" you add as argument is still necessary, but I think you can keep it by changing capabilities in the code above such as:

```
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False,
                                     'args': ['--disable-extensions'] }
               }
```

Both works for me and I don't get the error anymore. My settings are a bit different (Chrome v63, ChromeDriver 2.35, Selenium 3.9 and Python 2.7) but I hope it will help you.

Comment: I was exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as above. Referencing the below link, the use of ".add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)" worked for me.

[What is python's equivalent of useAutomationExtension for selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099288/what-is-pythons-equivalent-of-useautomationextension-for-selenium)

Sample Code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driverPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to your Question:

Add the following ChromeOptions to overcome the error:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("test-type"); 
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc"); 
options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps"); 
options.addArguments("test-type=browser"); 
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Apologies as the code is in Java, you have to convert it into Python format.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Modified your code slightly for Python, and gave it a try. Still the same issue, unfortunately. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Searle can you ensure that you are not using equivalent Python code of `driver.manage().window().maximize()` later in the code?

Comment: Aside from the argument you mentioned above for maximizing the window, I haven't touched parameters regarding position or size.

Comment: @Searle Can you clear the browser cache once & kill all the chrome driver instances from Task manager? I would suggest to restart the PC once. This Chrome configuration was working well till today evening my time.

Comment: @Searle You may need to run the CCleaner once to remove the unwanted stuff from your Temp folder & your system.

Comment: Logged out and back in, and then executed the same code. Same error. I wasn't receiving this error yesterday, it was an overnight Chrome update to v57.xxx.

Comment: @Searle was just wondering shouldn't it be `opts=ChromeOptions()`

Comment: I'm using `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options` to import the Options class, and then I'm just instantiating it. Just another coding difference.