# Failed to load extension from popup box while running selenium scripts

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I get the following popup box when I try to run my selenium script in java:

```
Failed to load extension from:
C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir20432_5430\internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
```

I have tried `chromeoption` `arguments` I have found in other pages. But none seems to work.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class testClass {

     public static String driverPath = "D:/Selenium/Chrome Driver latest/chromedriver.exe";
     public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

I am forced to handle that popup manually. How do I get rid of it ?

Comment: What kind of pop-up is it? Can you share a snapshot?

Comment: @Dev The same pop as shown in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079018/selenium-chromedriver-failed-to-load-extension)

Comment: so my previous solution doesn't works for you. Can you confirm if you have the admin privileges?

Comment: What is your test environment configuration? Selenium, ChromeDriver & Chrome version?

Comment: No I do not have admin privileges. Selenium - 3.4.0, Chrome Driver - 2.29, Chrome - 58.0.3029.81. My test environment is SSL enabled.

Comment: Can you try to clean up your machine through CCleaner once, reboot your system & try to retest?

Comment: Tried. Still not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and I finally found a working answer in another thread.
[Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator#answer-44884633)

The following line did the trickt for me

```
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

There are some trade-offs mentioned in the link, like window resizing operations with the Chrome automation extension aren't possible anymore. Anyway, starting with the start-maximized argument still worked fine in my code.

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was looking for this for a very long time.

Comment: This answer works for NightwatchJS as well. In your `nightwatch.json` config file, do:
`{"test_settings":{"default":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"useAutomationExtension":false}}}}}`

Comment: I tried everywhere and couldn't resolve it  but you have given the correct statement to overcome this. thank you Markus sir

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest compatible `chromedriver.exe` will resolve the issue.